# Equivalence relations on $\{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$

Tags: equivalence-relations

Well, I am having problem with understanding why the minimum elements of an equivalence relation on the Cartesian Product $\{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$ is $3$. 
In our lecture the explanation was, that we have defined transitivity  for three elements (see bellow, the definition), thus we need a minimum of $3$ different elements.

But in this post 
[Equivalence relation on set $\{0,1,2,3\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234266/equivalence-relation-on-set-0-1-2-3)

They argue, that the definition:

$$aRb ∧ bRc ⇒ aRc$$

does not state that $a, b, c$ have to be distinct. Thus since we have the pairs $\{\{1,1\}, \{2,2\}, \{3,3\}\}$ which are the minimum amount of elements of an equivalence relation.

Which is now the right explanation?

I would argue, that since an equivalence relation must be defined on all elements of a set, thus the most trivial one is $\{\{1,1\}, \{2,2\}, \{3,3\}\}$ which is the smallest as well. 
To make it clear: we can define an equivalence relation on a set with one element, right?

Comment: You need to distinguish between unordered pairs, $\{x,y\}$ and ordered pairs, $(x,y)$ or $\langle x,y\rangle$. These are **entirely** different things.

Answer (score 2):

The reflexivity condition states that a binary relation $R \subseteq A \times A$ is reflexive if we have that $x R x$ for all $x \in A$.

But the transitivity condition is *implicative*. It says that for all $x,y,z \in A$ we have that *if* $x R y$ and $y R z$ *then* $x R z$. Therefore we do not require that the elements $x,y,z$ must be distinct.

Comment: Thank you! So actually every set, which is not the empty set, is an equivalence relation?

Comment: No, that is certainly not the case. Now I am worried.

Comment: Hupps, I meant every set with one element

Comment: with ONLY one element

Comment: Every singleton set $\{ a \}$ gives rise to an equivalence relation $R = \{ (a,a) \}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation!

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric means if $(1,2) \in R$, then $(2,1) \in R$. In your example, all elements are of the form $(1,1)$ so it is true.

A set X is transitive if whenever an element 1 is related to an element 2, and 2 is in turn related to an element 3, then 1 is also related to 3. Its like they have similarity.

In your case 1 = 2 = 3.

And yes we can define an equivalence relation on one element set also.